# WPF Chromeless Button with Bound image state and hover image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a chromeless button in a WPF application that uses the XAML style below:
However, there are 2 things that I'm trying to do with it.

1. I want the displayed image to be one of two images, depending on a binding property from the datacontext of the template the button is in.  The property is a boolean.  Show one image if False, the other if True.
2. I would like the image shown to change when the mouse hovers over the button and to be the image that would be shown when above bound property is True.

I've tried several things, but nothing really seems to work.  I tried a converter with the bound value like this:

```
        <x:ArrayExtension x:Key="ThumbsDown" Type="BitmapImage">
            <BitmapImage UriSource="/Elpis;component/Images/thumbDown.png" />
            <BitmapImage UriSource="/Elpis;component/Images/thumbBan.png" />
        </x:ArrayExtension>

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var data = (object[])parameter;

            if (data.Length != 2 || value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(bool))
                return data[0];

            if(!((bool)value))
                return data[0];
            else
                return data[1];
        }

<Button Name="btnThumbDown" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource NoChromeButton}" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                            Background="Transparent"
                                            Click="btnThumbDown_Click">
                                <Image  Width="32" Height="32" Margin="2" 
                                        Source="{Binding Banned, 
                                                Converter={StaticResource binaryChooser}, 
                                                ConverterParameter={StaticResource ThumbsDown}}"/>
                            </Button>
```

But this causes 2 problems. Nothing I do for the hover image works anymore and the designer throws an exception.

The opacity trigger from below can go, as I really just want the hover now.

Any thoughts on how to make this properly work?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.75"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this by adding an `Image` control to the `ControlTemplate` of the button, and then create a `MultiDataTrigger` with one condition for `IsMouseOver` and one condition for the boolean property that you want to bind to. The trigger then sets the source of the image when active.

Below is a style that accomplishes this. I've assumed that the button has a DataContext which contains the boolean property, and that the boolean property is called MyBoolean.

```
<Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- I assume that the button has a DataContext with a boolean property called MyBoolean -->
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <!-- Not sure about what the button should look like, so I made it an image to the left
                            and the button's content to the right -->
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Grid.Column="0" Source="/Elpis;component/Images/thumbBan.png" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <!-- As I understand it, ThumbBan should be shown when IsMouseOver == True OR the bound boolean is true,
                        so if you invert that you could say that the ThumbDown image should be shown
                        when IsMouseOver == false AND the bound boolean is false, which is what this trigger does -->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=Chrome}" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding MyBoolean}" Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="/Elpis;component/Images/thumbDown.png" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.75"/>
                </Trigger>
                <!-- The trigger that sets opacity to 1 for IsMouseOver false is not needed, since 1 is the 
                        default and will be the opacity as long as the trigger above is not active -->
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*You might have to switch which image should be displayed when the trigger is active, if I misunderstod the requirements.*

The trick here is to use a `MultiDataTrigger` so that the two conditions you mention can be combined. Usually you would probably use a `Trigger` instead of a `DataTrigger` when binding to `IsMouseOver` of a control. But since you need a `DataTrigger` for the boolean property the `IsMouseOver` binding can be written as a `DataTrigger` by using the `ElementName` property of the binding. By doing that you make is possible to use a MultiDataTrigger to combine the two.

### UPDATE:

To add support for customizing the images used, and also which property to bind to, for each button instance I would subclass the `Button` class and add a couple of `DependencyProperties`.

```
public class ImageButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveImageUriProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ActiveImageUri", typeof(Uri), typeof(ImageButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InactiveImageUriProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InactiveImageUri", typeof(Uri), typeof(ImageButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsActive", typeof(bool), typeof(ImageButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public Uri ActiveImageUri
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(ActiveImageUriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveImageUriProperty, value); }
    }

    public Uri InactiveImageUri
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(InactiveImageUriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InactiveImageUriProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This class could then be used in the following way:

```
<SomeNamespace:ImageButton Height="23" Width="100" Content="Button 1"
    ActiveImageUri="/Elpis;component/Images/thumbBan.png"
    InactiveImageUri="/Elpis;component/Images/thumbDown.png"
    IsActive="{Binding MyBoolean}" />

<SomeNamespace:ImageButton Height="23" Width="100" Content="Button 2"
    ActiveImageUri="/Elpis;component/Images/someOtherImage.png"
    InactiveImageUri="/Elpis;component/Images/yetAnotherImage.png"
    IsActive="{Binding SomeOtherBooleanProperty}" />
```

The control template could then be modified to look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="SomeNamespace:ImageButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type SomeNamespace:ImageButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Grid.Column="0"
                        Source="{Binding ActiveImageUri, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- The "active" image should be shown when IsMouseOver == True OR the bound boolean is true,
                        so if you invert that you could say that the "inactive" image should be shown
                        when IsMouseOver == false AND the bound boolean is false, which is what this trigger does -->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsActive" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source"
                                Value="{Binding InactiveImageUri, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.75" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The major changes here is that the source for the image is set to the values of the dependency properties instead of hard coded URIs, and that the `MultiDataTrigger` has been changed into a `MultiTrigger` which binds to the dependency properties. Previously the path to the boolean property was also hard coded, but now that is configurable by changing the binding for the `IsActive` property when creating the button, as shown in the example above.

Comment: Ok... here's the one problem with that... This is a style that is used on MANY different buttons, all with different images. So I need to do this in a way that the images are set *outside* of the style that is just stored in a style.xaml file and refrenced on each button.

Comment: I have updated the answer to allow for configuring which images to use and which boolean property to bind to.

Comment: NICE... will give it a shot tonight. Figured it would take some code behind, but I'm totally OK with it just being a new control type.

Comment: Glad I could help! Just checking, you know that you actually accepted the other answer, right? Just wanted to make sure that it was intentional.

Comment: Oh man! So sorry... nope totally meant to accept yours. Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to do several things:

1. Set up `ImageBrush` resources for each of the images you want to show.
2. Create a `ControlTemplate` for the Button that has a built-in `Style` with a mouse-over `Trigger`.
3. Set the image on the `Button` by binding the `Background` property to one of the `ImageBrush` resources from point 1.
4. Use the mouse-over `Trigger` to change the `Background` property to the other `ImageBrush` resource.

See the code below for a simple example (you'll have to use your own images in place of "up" and "down").

```
    <Window x:Class="ButtonHover.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ButtonHover"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="227" Width="280">
        <Window.Resources>
            <ImageBrush x:Key="imageABrush"
                        ImageSource="/ButtonHover;component/Resources/up.png"/>
            <ImageBrush x:Key="imageBBrush"
                        ImageSource="/ButtonHover;component/Resources/down.png"/>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Border.Background"
                                        Value="{StaticResource imageABrush}"/>
                            </Style.Setters>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Border.Background"
                                            Value="{StaticResource imageBBrush}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Button Height="75"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="75"
                    Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

The key here is implementing the trigger on the `Style` of the `Border` rather than on the `Button` directly.  I couldn't get it to work when trying to set a property of the `Border` from a `Style` applied to the `Button`.  You can also replace the `Border` with a `Rectangle` or any other `ContentControl` with a `BackGround` property.

From here, customize as you see fit for your application.

Comment: How can I make the style work for multiple buttons that all have different images though?

Comment: I would suggest either making a `UserControl` or subclass of `Button` that can reference both a "Normal" image and a "MouseOver" image.  It appears, though, that Erik beat me to the punch.